# Can't Enable a button from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, telerik, entity-framework-6

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 function Enable_Butt() {               
     document.getElementById("<%=RadButton1.ClientID%>").disabled = false; // Doesn't Work                                                      
 }
</script>
```

i also tried this and it still does not work:

```
$find("<%=RadButton1.ClientID %>").set_enabled(true);
```

My code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
   <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server"  SingleClick="true" SingleClickText="Processing..." AutoPostBack="true" OnClick="Create_Order_Click" Text="Create Order" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="12" BackColor="#333333" ForeColor="White" Skin="Bootstrap" CssClass="auto-style5"  >
   </telerik:RadButton>
   <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="5000" ></asp:Timer>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RadButton8" EventName="Click" />
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), " ", "Enable_Butt()", true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the attribute altogether.

```
document.getElementById("<%=RadButton1.ClientID%>").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

For an example click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp)

Comment: I've Tried this one too and nothing changed

Comment: does this return anything? maybe the id is wrong? document.getElementById("<%=RadButton1.ClientID%>")

Comment: Actually I've Tried All of the possibilities and i got nothing

Comment: most probably the id you are trying to select is wrong. try selecting the element with inspect element and see what the ID of the element is.

Comment: I"ve Tried it with a new button (not RadButton) now and it worked perfectly so the problem was in the telerik button

Comment: Keep in mind the RadButton is a javascript control. There are actually methods for this on the control. It's not a problem, it's just the wrong usage. This should have also done what you were looking for.  $telerik.findButton("<=RadButton1.ClientID %>").set_enabled(true);

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("RadButton1").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

For the disabled property you need to do like so.

```
document.getElementById("<%=RadButton1.ClientID%>").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Reference - [removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)

Comment: I've Tried this one too